# Can 2 WritableByteChannels be used at the same time?

Tags: android, nio, channel

When I write directly to 2 outputstreams, everything works fine. When I try to write to 2 channels though, the second one seemingly does not receive it.

Does anyone know if 2 WritableByteChannels can be written to at the same time? If not, any other ideas of what I can do to perform the same action still using NIO/Channels?

```
connection2 = new Socket(Resource.LAN_DEV2_IP_ADDRESS, Resource.LAN_DEV2_SOCKET_PORT); 
out2 = connection2.getOutputStream(); 

connection = new Socket(Resource.LAN_HOST_IP_ADDRESS, Resource.LAN_HOST_SOCKET_PORT); 
out = connection.getOutputStream();         

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename);

in = new FileInputStream(f);
fic = in.getChannel();
fsize = fic.size();
channel2 = Channels.newChannel(out2); 
channel = Channels.newChannel(out); 

//Send Header
byte[] p = createHeaderPacket(filename, f.length());
out2.write(p); // Received correctly
out.write(p);  // Received correctly

//Send file
long currPos = 0;
while (currPos < fsize)
{
    if (fsize - currPos < Resource.MEMORY_ALLOC_SIZE)
    {                       
        mappedByteBuffer = fic.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, currPos, fsize - currPos);
        channel2.write(mappedByteBuffer); // Received correctly
        channel.write(mappedByteBuffer);  // Never received
        currPos = fsize;
    }
    else
    {
        mappedByteBuffer = fic.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, currPos, Resource.MEMORY_ALLOC_SIZE);
        channel2.write(mappedByteBuffer); // Received correctly
        channel.write(mappedByteBuffer);  // Never received
        currPos += Resource.MEMORY_ALLOC_SIZE;
    }
}
```

Comment: mappedByteBuffer is being erased after the first channel uses it. I created a second mappedByteBuffer performing the same mapping and it works. However, it's not as efficient as I'd like it to be. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course multiple channels can be used at the same time, but more to the point that's a terrible way to send a file. Creating lots of MappedByteBuffers causes all kinds of problems as the underlying mapped regions are never released. Just open it as a normal channel and use the canonical NIO copy loop:

```
while (in.read(buffer) >= 0 || buffer.position() > 0)
{
    buffer.flip();
    out.write(buffer);
    buffer.compact();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
channel2.write(mappedByteBuffer.duplicate());
channel.write(mappedByteBuffer);
```

The way to understand NIO Buffers is to keep in mind its basic properties:

- the underlying data store (which is commonly an ordinary byte array, but can be other things, such as a memory-mapped region of a file);
- the start and **capacity** within that underlying space;
- your current **position** in the buffer; and
- the **limit** of the buffer.

All buffer operations provided by NIO are documented in terms of how the operation affects these properties. For example, the [`WritableByteChannel.write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/WritableByteChannel.html#write%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) documentation tells us that:

- Between 0 and `src.remaining()` (inclusive) bytes will be written to the channel; and
- If `count` bytes were written, the ByteBuffer's *position* will be increased by `count` when `write()` returns.

So looking at your original code:

```
channel2.write(mappedByteBuffer); // Received correctly
channel.write(mappedByteBuffer);  // Never received
```

If the first write writes the entire remaining `mappedByteBuffer` to `channel2`, after that statement `mappedByteBuffer.remaining()` will be zero, so the write to `channel` will not write any bytes at all.

Hence my suggestion above to use [`ByteBuffer.duplicate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#duplicate%28%29) on the first write. This method returns a new `ByteBuffer` object which:

- shares the original buffer's underlying store (so you're not making an unnecessary copy in memory of the actual bytes you want to write twice); but
- has its own position (and remaining) values, so when `channel2.write()` adjusts that (duplicate) ByteBuffer's position, it will leave the position unchanged in the original buffer,

so `channel.write()` will still receive the intended range of bytes.

As an alternative, you could also write:

```
mappedByteBuffer.mark(); // store the current position
channel2.write(mappedByteBuffer);
mappedByteBuffer.reset(); // move position to the previously marked position
channel.write(mappedByteBuffer);
```

---

I'm also inclined to agree with EJP's point that you're probably not making the best use of `MappedByteBuffer` here. You could simplify your copying loop to:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Resource.MEMORY_ALLOC_SIZE);
while (fic.read(buffer) >= 0) {
    buffer.flip();
    channel2.write(buffer.duplicate());
    channel.write(buffer);
}
```

Here the `read()` method increases position by the number of bytes read from the channel, then the `flip()` method sets the *limit* to that position and the position back to 0, which means the bytes you've just read are in the remaining range that `write()` will consume.

However, you'll notice that EJP's loop is a little more complicated than that. That's because write operations on channels might not necessarily write every remaining byte. (The `write()` documentation gives the example of a networking socket opened in non-blocking mode.) However that sample code (and the similar sample in the documentation of `ByteBuffer.compact()`) relies on the fact that you're only writing to a single channel; when you're writing to two different channels, you have to handle the fact that the two channels might accept a different number of bytes. So:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Resource.MEMORY_ALLOC_SIZE);
while (fic.read(buffer) >= 0) {
    buffer.flip();

    buffer.mark();
    while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
        channel2.write(buffer);
    }

    buffer.reset():
    while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
        channel.write(buffer);
    }

    buffer.clear();
}
```